# [Microsoft Teams bot]Call icon doesn't appear in the bot channel #1636

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I have created a bot and registered it in Bot Framework without an Azure subscription by using the legacy portal and I checked "enable calling" checkbox, but when I open the bot in teams I can't find the call icon, but when I upload the manifest file in app studio tool then install the bot the icon appears.
i used this doc to register my bot services [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams#register-your-web-service-with-the-bot-framework)
[image]

Comment: Did you switch Teams to Developer Preview?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro

Comment: Yes I switched it, icons appears only when using app studio approach

Comment: Try to open the Bot as an app, click the Bot icon on the left toolbar of Teams (below Chat, Teams, Calendars etc...). If you don't see the icon in the toolbar, click the three dots, Bot will be there.

Comment: Ok when I open the bot as an app it is appearing but this means w have to upload the manifest file using the app studio and we can't use the legacy portal in bot framework ?

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. The app manifest has the setting for enabling calling for Bot.

Comment: My understanding that I can use Microsoft bot framework to set the bot setting or the app studio, is that wrong ?

Comment: You need to enable calling for the bot in the bot framework and add in the manifest using app studio.